# Wordpress image Thumbnail

Tags: image, wordpress, post, thumbnails, blogs

I'm trying to find a solution how to display only the thumbnail imagen on the main page of the blog and inside the post display all other images atached to the post.

I've googled it with no luck... Can anyone help?

Here you can see what I mean: blog.turdidesigns.com

I'm new to wordpress, so I appologise if this is a stupid question.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

in your index.php file replace the_content(); with the_excerpt();

Also, this might be in a loop, so make sure you replace this for articles lists (category, archive, search), not in single loop.

Comment: then you have to modify content.php

Answer (score 0):

in my index php I don't have this...

Here is what I have:
in my theme folder infex php I only have this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="art-layout-wrapper">

    <div class="art-content-layout">

        <div class="art-content-layout-row">

            <div class="art-layout-cell art-content">

            <?php get_sidebar('top'); ?>

            <?php 

                if(have_posts()) {



                    /* Display navigation to next/previous pages when applicable */

                    if ( theme_get_option('theme_' . (theme_is_home() ? 'home_' : '') . 'top_posts_navigation' ) ) {

                        theme_page_navigation();

                    }



                    /* Start the Loop */ 

                    while (have_posts()) {

                        the_post();

                        get_template_part('content', get_post_format());

                    }



                    /* Display navigation to next/previous pages when applicable */

                    if (theme_get_option('theme_bottom_posts_navigation')) {

                         theme_page_navigation();

                    }



                } else {



                     theme_404_content();



                } 

            ?>

            <?php get_sidebar('bottom'); ?>

              <div class="cleared"></div>

            </div>

            <div class="art-layout-cell art-sidebar1">

              <?php get_sidebar('default'); ?>

              <div class="cleared"></div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>

<div class="cleared"></div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I did this theme with Artisteer, so don't judge me too much ;)

Comment: if you can show us what's going on get_template_part('content', get_post_format()); may be we can help you. the file should named something like content-post.php or content-index.php

Comment: I have 3 file, content.php , content-page.php and content-single.php witch one would you like to see?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply !!!

Here is the content.php code:

```
<?php



/**

 *

 * content*.php

 *

 * The post format template. You can change the structure of your posts or add/remove post elements here.

 * 

 * 'id' - post id

 * 'class' - post class

 * 'thumbnail' - post icon

 * 'title' - post title

 * 'before' - post header metadata

 * 'content' - post content

 * 'after' - post footer metadata

 * 

 * To create a new custom post format template you must create a file "content-YourTemplateName.php"

 * Then copy the contents of the existing content.php into your file and edit it the way you want.

 * 

 * Change an existing get_template_part() function as follows:

 * get_template_part('content', 'YourTemplateName');

 *

 */ 



    global $post;

    theme_post_wrapper(

        array(

                'id' => theme_get_post_id(), 

                'class' => theme_get_post_class(),

                'thumbnail' => theme_get_post_thumbnail(),

                'title' => '<a href="' . get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '" rel="bookmark" title="' . strip_tags(get_the_title()) . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a>', 

        'heading' => theme_get_option('theme_'.(is_single()?'single':'posts').'_article_title_tag'),

                'before' => theme_get_metadata_icons( 'date,author,edit', 'header' ),

                'content' => theme_get_excerpt(), 

                'after' => theme_get_metadata_icons( 'category,tag,comments', 'footer' )

        )

    );

?>
```